# jquery Validation for multiple forms

Tags: jquery, validation

i am trying to do validation for multiple forms with same name
but i failed
here is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input.email").each(function(){
    $.validator.addMethod("email", function(value, element) {  
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/i.test(value);  
    }, "Please enter a valid email address.");               
        });
        $("#signup").validate({
                rules: {
                        email: "required email",


                },
 });
    });

</script>

<form method="post" action="jqueryregthank.html" name="signup" id="signup">
<input type="text" name="email[]" id='email'/><br />
<input type="text" name="email[]" id='email'/><br />
<input type="text" name="email[]" id='email'/><br />
<input type="submit" value=" Sign-UP " name='SUBMIT' id="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

i hope someone can help me

Comment: You cannot use several fields sharing the same id, its against the html/xhtml specification

Comment: Also the jquery target fields with a class named email but you're using id"s. So change id to class instead...

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
In a web page , There cannot be two elements with the same IDs.
So Change it to

```
<input type="text" name="email[]" class='email'/><br />
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just specify which fields to validate in your $.each selector.

```
$("input[name=email]").each(function(){
```

Also, the HTML ID tag must be unique or your page will act funky. A *class* named `email` would be better suited for your example.